# Any good photo browsing library for Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Any good photo browsing library for Objective C, except Three20 ?

Answer (score 1):

try this: [PhotoViewer by enormego](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) and [KTPhotoBrowser by kirbyt](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser)

Comment: Tried KTPhotoBrowser, it is quite good and clean

Answer (score 0):

Try with Assert library... or else simply use UIImagePickerController

Comment: What is Assert library ? Any sample ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is a small spelling mistake... Its Asset Library..

Here is the sample code..

[Sample code](http://icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/comment-page-1/)

Comment: Sorry, UIImagePickerController + Asset Library seems not easy to use.

Answer (score -3):

try Three20 framework

Comment: From the original question: "except Three20" ;)